# Как перевести формат JDraweble в обычный TBitmap? Android Delphi XE8

Tags: android, delphi, radstudio, delphi-xe7

При помощи данного кода, я получаю список приложений установленных на Android устройстве:

```
var
  PM: JPackageManager;
  mainIntent: JIntent;
  LaunchIntent: JIntent;
  pkgAppsList: JList;
  ri: JResolveInfo;
  iter: JIterator;
  midlist : TStringList;
begin
  PM := SharedActivityContext.getPackageManager;
  mainIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN, nil);
  mainIntent.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  pkgAppsList := PM.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
  midlist := TStringList;
  iter := pkgAppsList.iterator;
  while iter.hasNext do
  begin
    ri := TJResolveInfo.Wrap((iter.next as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    mIdList.Add(ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
  end;
end;
```

Что бы получить иконку приложения, нужно использовать функцию:

```
ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadicon(pm)
```

Но получаемый результат будет в формате **JDraweble**.
Как перевести формат **JDraweble** в обычный **TBitmap**?

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось очень просто:

```
var
...
 Drawable: JDrawable;
 mBitmap: JBitmap;
 Surface: TBitmapSurface;
...
begin
...
Drawable:= ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(PM);
 mBitmap := TJBitmapDrawable.Wrap((Drawable as ILocalObject).GetObjectID).getBitmap;
 Surface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
 JBitmapToSurface(mBitmap, Surface);
 image1.Bitmap.Assign(Surface);
  Surface.Free;
...
```